# WPF Text in TextBlock with TextWrapping contained in CheckBox or Radiobutton is lost if Hypen is present in string

Tags: wpf, xaml, word-wrap

I have a very strange behavior and i am desperate by now. I Have a Big enough container to fit Checkboxes defined below, but some others have more text so i use TextWrapping, Probem is that, hyphen presence in text involves some magic trimming. Here is the code:

```
<CheckBox>
<TextBlock Text="Media-Info Panel" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</CheckBox>

<CheckBox >
<TextBlock Text="Панель Медиа-Информации" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</CheckBox>
```

CheckBoxes in GUI will look like this

Media-Info
Панель Медиа-

After some testing and adding text to these checkboxes i found that hyphen presence removes the last word in the string. BTW i tried to set IsHyphenationEnabled to False - didn't help

After additional testing, i've finally found the problem if fontsize is 12, it reproduces, if we set fontsize to 13, it works fine. Should we set it to 13.3 or 15 it starts reproducing...
What foul magic is this?

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Comment: I also have this problem with a text block inside a listbox in a popup. It is very annoying.